# Difference of TermCriteria type in OpenCV : COUNT and MAX_ITER

Tags: opencv

[The doc page](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d9/d5d/classcv_1_1TermCriteria.html#aa6ec470a6a29edadcdd5e94e114960f6) of `TermCriteria` says that the `MAX_ITER` is the same as `COUNT` and the type can be one of : `COUNT`, `EPS` or `COUNT + EPS`. I am wondering whether there is a difference between `COUNT + EPS` and `MAX_ITER + EPS`. I found that in different places, there are these two different styles. Would that lead to different effects while running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. COUNT and MAX_ITER mean the same. They have the same value, hence are indistinguishable.

Well, their *meaning* depends on what function takes a TermCriteria tuple/struct/object. Still, same value means the identifiers are interchangeable.

Those named constants live in an enum. The values are chosen to be bits in a bit field. So they're actually **flags** and should, ordinarily, be combined with `|` (bitwise OR operator).

The `+` is a funny custom and probably because of the following... if you give two termination criteria, an algorithm terminates if any of them becomes true. So one could say *both* the one *and* the other are given... and now people get their brain gyri twisted thinking of "and" and "or". Combining those flags with `+` sidesteps that nicely.

```
cv.TermCriteria_COUNT    == 1
cv.TermCriteria_MAX_ITER == 1
cv.TermCriteria_EPS      == 2
```

so your choices are:

```
COUNT (means MAX_ITER)
MAX_ITER (means COUNT)
EPS
COUNT + EPS
MAX_ITER + EPS
```

Beware that you **don't say** `COUNT + MAX_ITER` (*wrong!*) because that is `1 + 1 = 2` and *that* is now `EPS`, which isn't what that expression was supposed to express.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation may not contain all the information, and it is generated from OpenCV public header files (via doxygen and its config file).

Just use an IDE/Editor, browsing the source code, search `TermCriteria`, and will see `MAX_ITER` and `COUNT` enumeration element values. Should be same.